# GNU Global installation on windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnu

I want to install GNU Global to configure pascal's extension in VS code but i haven't found it yet. Please help me by giving a link to download it or anything else.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jaycetyle.vscode-gnu-global

Comment: And from that: https://www.gnu.org/software/global/download.html

Comment: And from that: http://adoxa.altervista.org/global/